# Why is my jGRASP project file so bloated?

Tags: java, project, jgrasp

For several years I've maintained a number of Java projects using the jGRASP IDE. These projects tend have around 20 or so source files apiece. I'm used to the project files (.gpj) being fairly readable in an editor, and around 4 KB in size.

Recently, however, one of them has exploded in size up to 120 KB. Almost the entire size is taken by line 17 which starts off looking like this:

`[\012  grasp [\012   legendy -382.20000000000005\012   legendx -408.40909090909116\012   version 1\012   winflags 3\012   eheight 880\012   ewidth 1600\012   iheight 300\012   iwidth 792\012   height 880\012   width 1608\012   wbp 0\012   initlayout 0\012   yoffs 12.149360103651361\012   xoffs 1.0597621285392052\012   scale 0.8333333333333334\012   args ""\012   otherflags 139\012   shallowjar 1\012   visflags 118423807\012  ]\012  directed 1\012  node [\012   ClassInfo [\012    fields "$VALUES\\011[LAlignment;\\011\\0114122\\011\\011\\011Alignment\011Chaotic\\011LAlignment;\\011\\01116409\\011\\011\\011Alignment\011Lawful\\011LAlignment;\\011\\01116409\\011\\011\\011Alignment\011Neutral\\011LAlignment;\\011\\01116409\\011\\011\\011Alignment\011Alignment\\011(Ljava/lang/String;I)V\\011c\\0112\\011\\011()V\\011Alignment\011<clinit>\\011()V\\011\\0118\\011\\011\\011Alignment\011getFromChar\\011(C)LAlignment;\\011\\0119\\011\\011\\011Alignment\011random\\011()LAlignment;\\011\\0119\\011\\011\\011Alignment\011valueOf\\011(Ljava/lang/String;)LAlignment;\\011\\0119\\011\\011\\011Alignment\011values\\011()[LAlignment;\\011\\0119\\011\\011\\011Alignment"\012`

And it goes on like that for over 100K characters worth.

Why did this particular project file blow up on me, and how can I reset it or clear it out so it's not taking so much space and breaking my diff tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the layout for the UML diagram, which is stored with the project. If you have a lot of files or last displayed the UML with referenced Java classes included, that can get large.

I have a project with 90 files for which UML was generated, and the project file is 77K. If your project is smaller than that, you can probably display UML, turn off "View" -> "Visible Objects" -> "External References" and save the project and it should shrink.

Comment: Aha, thanks a bunch for that. It's true that this is the only project I've turned on the UML for. Only 33 files, tried turning of external references visibility, but that didn't shrink it (possibly I have no external dependencies). Nonetheless I actually like having the UML mapped out there, so I guess I'll keep it for now. Bounty incoming.